# How to securely pass secrets if I'm deploying my app n the old school way, rather than using Docker, Heroku, cloud etc?

Tags: secret-sharing

[Is it unsafe to use environmental variables for secret data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197784/is-it-unsafe-to-use-environmental-variables-for-secret-data)

^^ according to that question and answers:

- Environment variables are a poor (though perhaps passable, as per Forest's comment) way to store secrets;
- The preferred way is to use platform-provided ways to store secrets (Docker, Heroku, AWS, etc all provide such ways)

But all of this precludes the good old deployment that consists of just running the executable on our dedicated server.

I've once seen secrets stored in an encrypted configuration file with the encryption key being hardcoded in the app itself. It seems to me that such a scheme is pretty poor, however perhaps it is an improvement upon plaintext configuraiton variables?